# How to stack all images in a directory vertically into one long image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to merge images together into one long image. The images are all in one folder and have the same file name format `group1.X.jpg` with `X` being a number, starting at 0. I've tried using `img.paste` to merge the images together.
This is basically what I've been trying:

```python
    img1 = Image.open(directory + filePrefix + str(fileFirst) + fileExtension)
    w, h = img1.size
    h = h * fileCount
    img = Image.new("RGB", (w, h))
    tmpImg = img.load()
    console.log("Setup Complete")
    number = 0
    for number in track(range(fileCount - 1)):
        imgPaste = Image.open(dir + prefix + str(number) + extension)
        if not number >= fileCount:
            Image.Image.paste(tmpImg, imgPaste, (0, h * (number + 1)))
        number += 1
    img.save(file)

stitch(directory, filePrefix, fileExtension)
```

The above code, when ran, outputs the following:

````python
Working... ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━   0% -:--:--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marcus\Desktop\Stuff\Files\code\webtoonstitcher.py", line 36, in <module>
    stitch(directory, filePrefix, fileExtension)
  File "c:\Users\marcus\Desktop\Stuff\Files\code\webtoonstitcher.py", line 32, in stitch
    Image.Image.paste(tmpImg, imgPaste, (0, h * (number + 1)))
  File "C:\Users\marcus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1619, in paste
    if self.mode != im.mode:
AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'mode'```
````

Comment: Your first call is `Image.open(directory + filePrefix + str(fileFirst) + fileExtension)` but inside your loop you are using different variables: `Image.open(dir + prefix + str(number) + extension)`. Is this correct?

Comment: There's no real need to write any Python to do this, unless you are trying to learn. You can just use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal on macOS, Linux or Windows. `magick *.jpg -append result.jpg` Or if you want them 3-across and however tall, `magick montage -tile 3x *.jpg result.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get list of all images using `glob` and then just iterate through that list:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image


def stitch(directory, file_prefix, file_extension):
    files = glob.glob(directory + f'{file_prefix}*.{file_extension}')
    images = [Image.open(file) for file in files]
    background_width = max([image.width for image in images])
    background_height = sum([image.height for image in images])
    background = Image.new('RGBA', (background_width, background_height), (255, 255, 255, 255))
    y = 0
    for image in images:
        background.paste(image, (0, y))
        y += image.height
    background.save('image.png')


stitch('', 'group1', 'png')
```

Sample output:

[image: Fruits]

Comment: I tried this, and it works great except for the fact that it seems to paste the images in the wrong order. I have the images named similarly. I've narrowed it down to the array of images not being in the right order, so how would I sort the array? `.sort` throws a `TypeError` due to `<`. I tried to sort the array of file names but that led to `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: So fortunately the program I used to get the images had a delay between the creation of each image so I could put the original `glob.glob()` call in a `sorted()`: `sorted(glob.glob(dir + f'{file_prefix}*.{file_extension}'), key=os.path.getmtime)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
h = h * fileCount
img = Image.new("RGB", (w, h))
```

You should delete the first line and change the second line to:

```
img = Image.new("RGB", (w, h * fileCount))
```

Otherwise your `h` will be far too big when you use it later to calculate the offset for `paste()`.